# Script to Move Data in One Workbook to Another Workbook Within Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script written to move data to another sheet within a workbook when a user enters "5" or "W" in a specific column.

I'd like this script to work the exact same way listed below but instead of moving the data to another sheet within the same workbook, I'd like to instead move the data to a separate workbook within google sheets.

I am relatively new to writing scripts for google sheets, and any assistance/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```html
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  
  if (s.getName() == "DENIALS" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "5") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORKED_DENIALS_ARCHIVE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

  if (s.getName() == "DENIALS" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "W") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORKED_DENIALS_ARCHIVE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

  if (s.getName() == "OUTSTANDING" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "5") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORKED_OUTSTANDING_ARCHIVE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

  if (s.getName() == "OUTSTANDING" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "W") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WORKED_OUTSTANDING_ARCHIVE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] in what you've tried so far to accomplish modifying this  script to new workbook?

Comment: If you wish to have the format and values, try copying the sheet to the new spreadsheet and then use moveTo or copyTo from moved sheet to new sheet and then delete  moved sheet.  If you just want the values you can use getValues() and setValues().  I'm guessing that you might need and installable onEdit trigger.